# In django-parler what is the equivalent of "from hvad.forms import translatable_modelform_factory"

Tags: django, django-hvad, django-parler

I am moving a Django project from django-hvad to django-parler during a Django upgrade process.
In django-parler the API is almost the same as django-hvad and when I just replace the `from hvad.something import Something` it just works fine but I couldn't find an equivalent for `translatable_modelform_factory`
It does not exist in their documentation. Anybody has an idea on what can I use instead of this function and how can I use it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer and I put it here in case anyone searches for it in the future:
django-parler uses `TranslatableModelForm` class instead of translatable_modelform_factory function and it takes exactly the same arguments.